# Will my ios app get rejected for sending email?

Tags: ios, app-store

I am developing an application that uses the SKPSMTPMessage to send the forgotten user name and ID to the user's email, as the user has to login to access my app for security issue ,
does apple have restriction on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it's an open-source, so everyone can use that code, and Apple won't reject it for sending mails!

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply but does apple have any restriction over requiring the user email , as my application requires inserting the user's email so that in case he forgets the registered password a mail will be sent to the user's mail with the user ID and password .. does apple have any document concerning this issue ?

Comment: Well nope, the user can be multiple mail besides the one used for Apple store, so don't worry! It's a normal "You forgot your password?" form so there will be no problems :)